# Jquery validation with hidden contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The contents under the hidden div should be validated only when the div is active. But in my case the error message is not working for the case of  "Elephant".
Code is in http://jsfiddle.net/2eRsm/ for more details, thanks in advance

```
<form>
   Choose your animal 
<select id="selectMenu">
    <option></option>
    <option value="monkey">Monkey</option>
    <option value="elephant">Elephant</option>    
</select>
<div class="mon">Monkey:
    <input type="text" class="required" name="mon"/> 
    <p id="error-msg">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

<div class="ele">Elephant:
    <input type="text" class="required" name="ele"/>
     <p id="error-msg">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
<button>submit</button>    
</form>
//js
$(document).ready(function () {    
       $("#selectMenu").bind("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "monkey") {
            $(".mon").slideDown();
            $(".ele").slideUp();
        }
        else if($(this).val() =="elephant") {
            $(".ele").slideDown();
            $(".mon").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
$("button").click( function(){
    $("form").submit();   
});
$("form").validate({
    ignore:":hidden",
    rules: {
        name: ["mon", "ele"]
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( $('#error-msg') )
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        console.log( "error" );  
    },
    submitHandler: function( form ) {
        console.log( "no error" );
    }
});
//css
input {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 3px; 
 }
p{
    display:inline;
    color: red;
}
.mon,.ele{
        display: none; 
}*
```

Comment: Find me the bug? Have you tried something yourself? Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes, I tried to change the id of the p, I don't get error, It does not display the content of the p under elephant div, I though it might need separate id for each div

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you have duplicate ids. Because your validation puts the error in the element with `#error-msg`, it only places that in the first element it finds. So the second stays empty. You might try something with a classname (both elements can have the same classname)

Comment: How would you do if required fields need to display their own error message just beside, not collecting error in own place and it will confuse user for sure! yes the id are same, is there any way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used same id 2 times for error msg...
use different id
Try this for ...............http://jsfiddle.net/2eRsm/3/

```
<form>
   Choose your animal 
<select id="selectMenu">
    <option></option>
    <option value="monkey">Monkey</option>
    <option value="elephant">Elephant</option>    
</select>
<div class="mon">Monkey:
    <input type="text" class="required" name="mon"/> 
    <p id="error-msg">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>

<div class="ele">Elephant:
    <input type="text" class="required" name="ele"/>
     <p id="error-msg1">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
<button>submit</button>    
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is for Elephant not for Monkey, as it works even with same id in case of Monkey!

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it means I need several different ids. I don't know if the solution is scalable!

Answer (score 4):

2 time ID not good:

```
 <p id="error-msg">&nbsp;</p>
```

do this:

```
  <p class="error-msg">&nbsp;</p>
```

and then:

```
 error.appendTo( $('.error-msg') )
```

to reset it:

```
   $("#selectMenu").bind("change", function () {
   $('.error-msg').html("");
```

Comment: I tried it,but the error message shouldn't appear! Before submit is hit for case of "Elephant", as it would implicate user had in fact provided input! Which in this case is false!

Answer (score 0):

Your validation works, but since you have two elements with ID "error-msg", I'd wager your error message gets attached to the first match, which is hidden when "Elephant" is selected.